# ArcGIS Pro Python arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, personal-geodatabase

I have an ArcGIS Pro Python script (please note it's version 3+ and to be precise shows as 3.66) and when I run the following command, I get an error.

```
arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(out_folder_path, out_name)
```

The error is `module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'CreatePersonalGDB_management'`

The script runs fine when ran under Python 2.7 environment but that's not we need.

Basically, my goal is to copy all Features etc from a File Geodatbase into a Personal Geodatabase and that works by simply copying/pasting inside ArcCatalog. So I am pretty sure my issue is because of the limitation is ArcGIS Pro (and it's version of Python) support for Personal Geodatabase.

So how I do resolve this error? The users will likely not have Python 2.7 in their systems--only will have ArcGIS Pro. I am thinking of including path to a blank Personal Geodatabase .mdb file and simply use something like:

```
arcpy.Copy_management(target_gdb, target_mdb)
```

But throws an error that file maybe locked--which doesn't make sense because ArcCatalog is not open.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You receive the error `module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'CreatePersonalGDB_management'` because this tool does not exist in ArcGIS Pro.

ArcGIS Pro has *no* support for pGDB (personal geodatabases). Neither read, nor write.

You need to start with a supported datatype before moving to Pro. Shapefiles, fGDB, etc. So before moving to Pro, use ArcMap, ArcCatalog, or another software that supports pGDB to copy to a supported type.

Lots of discussion, grumbling and thoughts on the [idea](https://community.esri.com/ideas/12662-enable-arcgis-pro-to-access-esri-personal-geodatabases) to support pgdb in Pro.

Comment: Thank you. A dead-end was ahead, thanks to ESRI, and you helped me save some time not pursuing this further.